# Anybody tied High Throughtput Mining with NVidia GPGPU - Planning to buy a server

Tags: gpu-mining, mining, mining-hardware

I am planning to buy a server with following specs to follow my passion for mining currencies and make money too. Someone suggested me to buy this server.

Intel® C612 Chipset - Dual 1-Gigabit Ethernet - 4U GPU Server - 2000W (2+2) Redundant Power Supply
2 x Twenty-Two-Core Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2699A v4 2.40GHz 55MB Cache (145W)
8 x 32GB PC4-19200 2400MHz DDR4 ECC Registered Load-Reduced DIMM
No SATA Disk on Module for boot
No Optical Drive Support
8 x Integrated Video (Included with Motherboard)
8 x NVIDIA® Tesla™ K80 GPU Computing Accelerator - 24GB GDDR5 - Passive Cooler
Intel® Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2V2 Dual Port (2x RJ-45)
2 x Intel® SSD DC P3520 Series 1.2TB PCIe 3.0 x4 NVMe Solid State Addon Card
Replacement Chassis Top Cover (required for NVIDIA GeForce GTX graphics card support)

Since I am only into AltCoins and that too just cryptonotes have thought of buying the above server. Can someone calculate & suggest the hashrate it would be able to generate. Cost of this server is very high and would be putting in plenty of money to acquire it.

Any suggestions or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Regards, 
Pundit

Answer (score 1):

check on http://monerobenchmarks.info/ the tesla and xeon are both on the list